# Merge all .txt files in all subdirectories in one txt file

Tags: batch-file, text, merge, xcopy

I want to merge content of all .txt files in my directory (containing subdirectories) to one txt file. 
I need to do this:

```
xcopy text1.txt + text2.txt text3.txt
```

but in a for loop which takes all text files in current directory. i assume something like this:

```
for \r ___ in ___ do copy list.txt
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use one % instead of two %% to run it from the command line.

```
for /r "c:\folder" %%a in (*.txt) do type "%%a" >>"bigfile.txt"
```

Comment: for /r "c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\UJC\files\" %a in (*.txt) do type "%a" >>"c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\UJC\files\bigfile.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@echo off
set "folder=folder"
for /F %%a in ('dir /b /s %folder%') do (
 if "%%~xa" == ".txt" (
  (echo/------------------------------
  type %%~a
  echo/)>>"%~dp0list.txt"
)
)
```

Comment: Did you change `folder` to your main folder?